# Split the string in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

I have these below line of codes

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()); 
 string year = date.Year.ToString();
```

output of this will be

> 2014

Instead of `2014` i just need `14`.

Using `substring` is better or `ToString("yy");`?

any help appreciated.

Comment: If you really want to do it with string operations, use `date.Year.ToString().Substring(2)`. Of course, [Haedrian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22500596/107625) is the way to go.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string year = date.ToString("yy");
```

Will format your year into the 2 digit representation

[Full documentation on custom format strings here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string year = date.ToString("yy");
```

example

```
6/15/2009 -> 09
```